# no response from WCF when returning an Entity Framework object

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to return an Entity Framework object generated by Entity Framework database first in a WCF service.

This is my interface

```cs
namespace HiplotSystemService.services
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServiceUsuario
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
                   UriTemplate = "Useru")]
        object GetUsuario();
    }
}
```

My service class:

```cs
namespace HiplotSystemService.services
{
    public class ServiceUsuario : IServiceUsuario
    {
        public object GetUsuario()
        {
             using (HiplotSystemEntities datacontext = new HiplotSystemEntities())
             {
                 var response = datacontext.usuario.Where(x => x.id == 6).FirstOrDefault();
                 return response;
             }
         }
     }
}
```

When I call the service from postman, I can not get any response

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFHdA.png)

Despite Visual Studio says WCF answered with a 200 code:

```
{
  "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Request",
  "time": "2019-06-03T19:03:34.8763009Z",
  "tags": {
    "ai.cloud.roleInstance": "DESKTOP-5SD5F4O",
    "ai.operation.id": "6b308fdc12cc3748bf7522f1169a3c66",
    "ai.operation.name": "GET /services/ServiceUsuario.svc/Useru",
    "ai.location.ip": "::1",
    "ai.internal.sdkVersion": "web:2.10.0-32157"
  },
  "data": {
    "baseType": "RequestData",
    "baseData": {
      "ver": 2,
      "id": "|6b308fdc12cc3748bf7522f1169a3c66.5b1db8ff_",
      "name": "GET /services/ServiceUsuario.svc/Useru",
      "duration": "00:00:03.0628593",
      "success": true,
      "responseCode": "200",
      "url": "http://localhost:61768/services/ServiceUsuario.svc/Useru",
      "properties": {
        "DeveloperMode": "true",
        "_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors": "(Name:'Requests', Ver:'1.1')"
      }
    }
  }
```

Also if I throw an exception before the return, I can see the var response and it seems fine, it has the right user info. I have some POST methods and they work fine

Somethings I already tried:

- Use a user type instead var.
- Setting `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false` in `HiplotSystemEntities.Context.cs`
- Setting `base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false` in `HiplotSystemEntities.Context.tt`
- Return just a boolean - when I do this I can get the true or false in postman
- Select just some properties to return, but still don't get any response
- Return the object as a string, I get the object in the response but as string, obviously

Comment: The result is cast as `object`. You'll be able to see what that object is when you debug, but I don't think it will be serialized without a more specific type. That type represents a contract between the service and its consumers. It can't work if the thing returned can be literally any object.

Comment: I have also tried 
usuario response = datacontext.usuario.Where(x => x.id == 6).FirstOrDefault();
And also return a List<usuario>, but is the same problem

Answer (score 1):

For complex data types returned in WCF, use a data contract. WCF must know how to serialize and Deserialize the data to be transmitted before using it. Please refer to the example below.
**IService1.**

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate ="/MyTest",Method ="GET",RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        CompositeType Test();
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }

}
```

**Service1.cs**

```
   public CompositeType Test()
    {
        return new CompositeType()
        {
            StringValue = "Hello, busy world",
            BoolValue = true
        };
    }
```

**Result.**
[image]
Here is the official document, wish it is useful to you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

actually there is a simple solution for that. you can use `Stream` instead `object` as your out put. this way you can send back object.

```
return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("your json string"));
```